# Maven Webapp run in Eclipse but run base java code of Module?

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, web-applications, module

I have 2 project 
 1) Module for webapp, this is project contain some java class Utility.
 2) Webapp project using project (1).

I configuration to run project in Eclipse + Tomcat plugin, It run OK.

But when I change code of project (1) and run again, the webapp not unknow change. I must maven install again. Then run webapp is OK.

Please help me, ignore step run : maven install.

Answer (score 0):

You should  check the pom.xml files for both (1) and (2).
1. It should have two modules in pom.xml which is the parent of both (1) and (2).
2. In `pom.xml` of (2), (1) should be configed as  an dependency for it.

if its ok for above, build then in parent pom.xml path like
    `mvn package`

if build correctly, use command below for generating Eclipse project
    `mvn eclipse:eclipse`

and then import then to Eclipse.